# How to limit props.children.some to image type only?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Trying to fix following error:

> Property 'type' does not exist on type 'true | ReactChild |
> ReactFragment | ReactPortal'.   Property 'type' does not exist on type
> 'string'.ts(2339) any

`props.children` is of type `React.ReactNode & React.ReactNode[]`.

```
props.children.some(
  (child) => child && child.type && child.type.name === "image"
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to check the type in runtime(using code) or buildtime (using ts)?

Comment: @PrateekThapa Both I believe…

Comment: Could you write the component in the code? It would be helpful of what the component looks like

Comment: @PrateekThapa Code is pretty abstract… would you happen to know how to check if `child` is an element vs boolean, string etc…?

Comment: I posted the answer below, does that solve the problem.

Comment: @PrateekThapa Thanks for helping out… fixing some other issues to get code to run and I will follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [isValidElement()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#isvalidelement), it can be used as user-defined type guard whose return type is a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) of TypeScript. TypeScript will narrow the `child` to  `React.ReactElement<P>` interface which has a `type` property.

```
function isValidElement<P>(object: {} | null | undefined): object is ReactElement<P>;
```

`App.tsx`:

```
import React, { isValidElement } from 'react';

interface AppProps {
  children: React.ReactNode & React.ReactNode[];
}

export function App(props: AppProps) {
  const hasImage = props.children.some((child) => {
    return isValidElement(child) && child.type === 'img';
  });
  console.log('hasImage: ', hasImage);
  return <div>app</div>;
}
```

`App.test.tsx`:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { App } from './App';

describe('App', () => {
  test('should has image', () => {
    function Test() {
      return (
        <App>
          <img src="" alt="" />
          123
        </App>
      );
    }
    mount(<Test />);
  });

  test('should not has image', () => {
    function Test() {
      return (
        <App>
          <span>123</span>
          456
        </App>
      );
    }
    mount(<Test />);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68683422/App.test.tsx (17.681 s)
  App
    ✓ should has image (65 ms)
    ✓ should not has image (4 ms)

  console.log
    hasImage:  true

      at App (examples/68683422/App.tsx:11:11)

  console.log
    hasImage:  false

      at App (examples/68683422/App.tsx:11:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        19.194 s
```

package versions:

```json
"react": "^16.14.0",
"typescript": "^4.1.2"
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out! Would you happen to know why `console.log(child.type)` returns `function img(_a)` at my end?

Comment: `isValidElement()` is what I was looking for, thanks! Had to adapt answer a little given `child.type` is a function rather than a string. The following logic worked: `isValidElement<HTMLImageElement>(child) && typeof child.type !== "string" && child.type.name === "img"`.

Answer (score 0):

- To check whether the child is an element, boolean or string.

```
import { isValidElement } from 'react';


// check for valid element
isValidElement(child);

// to check for boolean
if (typeof child === "boolean")


// to check for string
if (typeof child === "string")
```